# KeyUp/KeyDown alternative for languages like Japanese, Chinese and Korean?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, cjk, textblock, ime

In a `TextBox`, I can't capture keystrokes for languages with special IMEs like Japanese and Korean because the IME is constantly deciding on different characters or syllables. KeyUp/KeyDown actually don't fire most of the time (backspace will fire if the IME isn't in the middle of a decision).

I need to capture the text in the TextBox before Enter is pressed.

Could you offer a suggestion?

Comment: Webforms? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: Sorry, Silverlight on Windows Phone. Wasn't sure if I should tag as such.

Comment: You have a phone with an Enter key???

Comment: @HansPassant So, I just read the wiki on the Enter key. Ha, ha. I just want to say that .NET will capture return with `Key.Enter`, and my keyboard says Enter on both return and enter. =/

Comment: Actually, I can't tell if you were joking. So here's a picture of the [WP7 keyboard](http://i.imgur.com/FCmDz.png).

Answer (score 0):

You could test for textbox change instead.

Comment: The closest matching event I could find was `TextInputUpdate`, but it doesn't fire either.